# ngbDatepicker - first character doesn't appear when manually typing a date

Tags: angular

I'm working with an ngbDatepicker control with a text input. The date can either be selected using the calendar or can manually be typed in. The problem is, when a date is selected with the calendar, highlighted, deleted, and you try typing a new date in, the first character typed doesn't show up. I think this has to do with a helper function I'm using, `sanitizeNgbDate`, but I can't tell why it's happening.

StackBlitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f57uu3?file=app%2Fdatepicker-popup.html

Template:

```
<form class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd"
             name="dp" ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker" [(ngModel)]="secondToDate">
      <div class="input-group-append">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary calendar" (click)="d.toggle()" type="button"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Controller:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbDate } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-datepicker-popup',
  templateUrl: './datepicker-popup.html'
})
export class NgbdDatepickerPopup {
  model;

  private _secondToDate: NgbDate;


  get secondToDate() {
    return this._secondToDate;
  }
  set secondToDate(value: NgbDate) {
    value = this.sanitizeNgbDate(value);
    this._secondToDate = value;
  }

  private sanitizeNgbDate(value: NgbDate) {
    if (!value) {
      return null;
    }
    const tDate = new Date(value.year, value.month - 1, value.day);
    if (!isNaN(tDate.getTime())) {
      return value;
    } else {
      return null;
    }

  }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.